# copy list into other list

Tags: c#, list

I know this is asked many times and i am trying to implement same . I have list below

```
internal class GenList
{

    public string Col1 { set; get; }
    public string Col2 { set; get; }

}

List<GenList> MainList = new List<GenList>();
```

I want to copy list into other list and dont want content to change in cloned list if something is changed in main list. So i am trying to do below

```
List<GenList> cloned = MainList.ConvertAll(GenList => new GenList {});
```

I dont know what to enter inside those curly braces in above line.

Comment: Your expression could be `(gl => new GenList {Col1 = gl.Col1, Col2 = gl.Col2})`

Comment: Is performance a concern?  If not, you could serialize/deserialize from a stream?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> dont want content to change in cloned list if something is changed in main list.

That sounds like you want a deep clone, basically. In other words, creating a new list where each element is a *copy* of an element in the original list, not just a reference to the same object as the original list refers to.

In your case, that's as simple as:

```
var cloned = MainList.ConvertAll(x => new GenList { Col1 = x.Col1, Col2 = x.Col2 });
```

Or with LINQ:

```
var cloned = MainList.Select(x => new GenList { Col1 = x.Col1, Col2 = x.Col2 })
                     .ToList();
```

But note that:

- If you add a new property, you will need to change this code
- If you add a property of a *mutable* type, you'd need to clone that too

Options to consider:

- Adding a `DeepClone()` method to `GenList`, to keep the logic in one place however many places need it.
- Adding a constructor instead: `GenList(GenList)` which copies appropriately
- Using immutable types instead (e.g. make `GenList` immutable) at which point shallow clones of collections are sufficient.

Comment: How to add mutable type property?

Comment: @Happy: Imagine you added `StringBuilder Col3 { get; set; }`. I'm not saying you will - I'm just saying you need to be careful if you do.

Comment: If possible give me good link to add mutable type property or if possible update answer. would be too much thankful to you

Comment: @Happy: It sounds like you're not sure what "mutable" means - you should research that yourself.

Comment: could you give me keyword to search. I tried mutable Properties but not getting desired result

Comment: @Happy: "Mutable type" would be a good starting point. For example, `string` is an *immutable* type, and `StringBuilder` is a *mutable* type.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick deep clone solution via serialization:

```
[Serializable]
public class GenList
{
    public string Col1 { set; get; }
    public string Col2 { set; get; }

    public GenList DeepClone()
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, this);

            stream.Position = 0; //reset stream

            var cloned = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as GenList;
            return cloned;
        }
    }
```

and a test to verify:

```
[TestClass]
public class DeepCloneTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ReferencesAreNotMaintained()
    {
        var object1 = new GenList() { Col1 = "a", Col2 = "b" };
        var cloned = object1.DeepClone();
        Assert.AreEqual(object1.Col1, cloned.Col1);
        Assert.AreEqual(object1.Col2, cloned.Col2);

        cloned.Col1 = "c";
        cloned.Col2 = "d";

        Assert.AreNotEqual(object1.Col1, cloned.Col1);
        Assert.AreNotEqual(object1.Col2, cloned.Col2);
    }
}
```